# lein-ritz fails on Windows with error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am attempting to use [lein-ritz](https://github.com/pallet/ritz/tree/develop/lein-ritz) from Windows and get this error.  Is there some way to get lein-ritz to not pass the classpath on the command line?

```
lein ritz
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory ""):
     CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
    at leiningen.core.eval$sh.doInvoke(eval.clj:158)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at leiningen.core.eval$fn__1963.invoke(eval.clj:211)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
    at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:283)
    at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:290)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at leiningen.ritz$eval_in_project.doInvoke(ritz.clj:72)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at leiningen.ritz$ritz.doInvoke(ritz.clj:116)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__1836.doInvoke(main.clj:149)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:189)
    at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:193)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__1899.invoke(main.clj:257)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:247)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:335)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:423)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the eval-in classloader might be able to help you overcome this limitation of Windows.  Try adding `:eval-in :classloader` to the project.clj as per https://github.com/pallet/ritz/tree/develop/nrepl