# Another error trying "lein ritz" - Unable to resolve var: main/warn-chaining in this context, compiling:(ritz/swank/project.clj:98:11)

Tags: clojure, leiningen

After solving [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287534/lein-ritz-fails-on-windows-with-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long) I am now getting another error running `lein ritz`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: main/warn-chaining in this context, compiling:(ritz/swank/project.clj:98:11)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6567)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3573)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6562)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5708)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6009)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6560)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6548)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5708)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you're running `lein ritz` outside of a project directory.

New versions of `ritz` will warn:

> Couldn't find project.clj, which is needed for ritz

But `lein ritz-nrepl` still results in an uncaught java runtime exception:

```
Unable to resolve var: main/warn-chaining in this context
```

**Solution:** cd to your project directory, and try again from there.

Comment: It is working now, after making sure it is in the project directory and downloading a ton of updates.  Thanks.